# MVC RememberMe Validation Glitch

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

In my MVC project the validator unintentionally requires that the RememberMe checkbox be checked upon logging in. On IE8, it will not allow the user to login unless they tick the Remember Me box. All other browsers are fine including IE7.

```
<input id="RememberMe" type="checkbox" value="true" name="RememberMe" data-val-required="The Remember me? field is required." data-val="false">
```

I tried to change the property in entity framework to a nullable bool? but this produces the error:

```
The best overloaded method match for 'WebMatrix.WebData.WebSecurity.Login(string, string, bool)' has some invalid argument
```

So, it doesn't look like I am able to change it to fix this issue. I have also tried over writing the property with jQuery but it gets changed back. This is really random and i'm suprised that this got over looked as it is out of the box technology. Any help would be much appreciated.

Here is the login model:

```
public class LoginModel
{
    [EmailAddressAttribute]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(80)]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

And this is the controller that does the login, as you can see it is the out of the box MVC stuff:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

And here is the View:

```
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<ol class="form">
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { id="txUserName" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password)
    </li>
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe, new { @class = "checkbox" })
        @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
    </li>
    <li class="form-buttons">
        <input type="submit" value="Log in" /> &nbsp; @Html.ActionLink("Forgot Password", "ForgotPassword", "Account")
    </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Post the code that handles the login

Comment: Ok I posted the code but accidently overwrote the old description :(

Comment: Do you have a view for this?

Comment: I have just added the view. Thanks.

Comment: Define "will not allow the user to login". Do you get an error? Does the login fail? Do you get an invalid model validation message?

Comment: When i type a user name and password and click submit in IE8 only, the Remember Me box gets highlighted red and it won't allow me to continue on the client side unless the Remember Me box is checked.

There is no script or server errors, i believe it is a ASP.NET MVC glitch at this point.

Comment: What if you check and then uncheck the box? do you still get the error?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research, this is said to be caused by IE7 & IE8 compatibility mode in Internet Explorer 10 only.

It will also cause other problems with unobtrusive jquery validation running under the same conditions.

Comment: Don't think you can. Just test in an Emulated IE instead of compat mode.